# How to combine Stack and Drawer navigations in React Native Navigation(version 6)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to combine Stack and Drawer navigations. I have some screens and want to show few of that screens label in drawer tab.

```
<RootNavigatorStack.Navigator>
  <RootNavigatorStack.Screen name="DrawerTab" component={DrawerNavigator} />

  <RootNavigatorStack.Screen
     name="PrivateStack"
     component={StackNavigator}
   />
</RootNavigatorStack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your `PrivateStack` as your `DrawerNavigator` component.

Guessing you have a DrawerNavigator which looks something like this:

```
<DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
  <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="ScreenOne" component={ScreenOne} />
  <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="PrivateStack" component={StackNavigator} />
</DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
```

Info on nesting navigators
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Comment: Yes you are true. But this time I should hide some screens from Drawer tab. Whant I understand , when I have Drawer and Stack navigations, I should wrap all those  in Drawer navigation container. Is it true?